# How to read the slash in “1/4 satin”?

Tags: material-selection, material-identification, weaving

I am not a native English speaker, and I would like to know how do you read “1/4 satin”?

Is it pronounced as one-by-four satin or as one-to-four satin when read out?

Please note that this use is related to the binding structure of textiles.

For instance, in the following texts: It is observed that when the weave is changed from 4 / 1 satin to 1 / 4 satin ， the average warp tensions at shedding and beaten-up increase.

thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is 1/4? If it is the normal notation about the weave, it would be an odd number of at least 5. My friend who weaves called it 'one in five' but I have no answer to the other details.

Answer (score 2):

It would be referred to as "1 in 4" satin and refers to the weave pattern.  4/1 satins would be warp faced twills and 1/4 satins would be weft faced twills.

[image: Pattern image of different twills]

For more information on this you can read all about it at  https://www.textileschool.com/articles/125/twill-weaves

Answer (score -4):

it is a fraction or ratio .. 1 out of 4 threads are satin

Comment: As satin is a way to weave, it is impossible to have one out of four threads in Satin (as you could have in cotton or some such.) So this 'answer' makes no sense.